# share hibernate-search indexes across multiple servers

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

currently we are aiming to do load balance 2 active servers 50/50.

Java application uses hibernate search locally, I have centralized this directory so both server uses the same directory.

I want to share hibernate indexing with multiple servers
I have set following so there is no locking between read/writefrom the servers
  property name="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy" value="none" 
Does anyone know if this will be an issue?

Comment: Is it not nice to state that this question is unclear *and* to broad?

Comment: For me It's both clear and precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really answer your question but I'd like to share some considerations.

We used this kind of configuration during years in production (no custom lock strategy) and we experimented so much problem (stale nfs file handle, dead lock and index corruption).

We tried to defer all the index updates operation to a single server using JMS but even in this mode we experimented some problems (much less than in the mode where update operation occurs on many servers however)

Note also that putting the index files on NFS is [strongly discouraged](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Lucene-index-on-NFS-td4011301.html)

We finally gave up hibernate search, for distributed indexes I'll personally advise to use elastic search.

However this is theoretically possible as stated there : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html/search-architecture.html#_lucene

> This mode targets non clustered applications, or clustered applications where the Directory is taking care of the locking strategy.

I don't really know how the "Directory" is expected to handle the locking strategy

The previously used datasource configuration regarding hibernate search :

```
<!-- hibernate search configuration -->
            <!-- index root folder location -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${env.ftindex.location.root}/${datasource.database}/${ftindex.folder}</prop>
            <!-- global analyzer -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.analyzer">custom_analyzer</prop>
            <!-- asynchronous indexing for performance considerations -->
            <prop key="org.hibernate.worker.execution">async</prop>
            <!-- max number of indexing operation to be processed asynchronously (before session flush) to avoid OutOfMemoryException -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.worker.buffer_queue.max">100</prop>
```